# HTML and ASP Button Conflict on IE

Tags: asp.net

I got a problem using two types of button on IE.
For this test i created a ASP.NET webpage in Visual Studio and added the code below inside Default.aspx

```
  <asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <form action="#" method="post">
      <input type="submit" name="test" value="Test!" class="button" title="Subscribe" />
    </form>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
    Hello <asp:Label ID="l1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
  </asp:Content>
```

The problem happens when i try to use the asp:button. It won´t work (no postback).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need the form attribute you can close the form from the master page and then reopen it after the form your adding. Something like this:

```
  <asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    </form>
    <form action="#" method="post">
      <input type="submit" name="test" value="Test!" class="button" title="Subscribe" />
    </form>
    <form action="#" method="post">
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
    Hello <asp:Label ID="l1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
  </asp:Content>
```

But I agree with Justin, why do you need a form within a form.

Comment: i don´t need it. i just don´t understand why i can´t do this.

Comment: @Makah - [Nested forms aren't valid in HTML](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/forms.html), most likely because they could cause confusion about which action to take on submit. A webpage with nested forms will lead to undefined behavior on the client-side, which is likely resulting in postback data that ASP.NET can't understand. What exactly that postback looks like probably depends on the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Your master page will already have a `form` element that contains the content area, so the form in your markup above is essentially a nested form. That's probably what's messing you up; in fact, I don't even know if it's valid to do that. Either way, you don't need the `form` there unless it has some kind of purpose you're not mentioning. I'd suggest removing it and trying again.